# What is the chance that a tribesman will poison you?

Tags: runescape

In Runescape what are the chances that a tribesman will poison you? I want to to the clean up game on Karamja and wanted to check out the monsters before I started.

Comment: For players using weapon poison, it is a 1 in 8 chance to poison an opponent while under the effects of a weapon poison potion. I *think* it is the same for tribesmen, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Also, something to consider, these guys drop Super Antipoison potions. So if you are poisoned, you can use those to cure yourself and to keep yourself immune.

Answer (score 1):

As for the actual chance of them poisoning you, the wiki has no information on it. That being said, the [wiki](https://runescape.wiki/w/Tribesman) does say that once poisoned you will be dealt 68 poison damage every 10 seconds. Nevertheless if your worried about just bring some super antipoison potions. Not only will they cure poison, but they will prevent you from being poisoned for approximately 6 minutes.

Comment: Fairly cheap too IIRC